# What is the term used "When a person is called in to work on a holiday"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Someone asked me about what term is used for a **person who is called in to work on a public holiday**. (He told me that it is called *pump of leave*, but he himself was not sure of it.)

So, there are two questions-

- What is that person called?
- What is that leave is called?

If there are specific terms for them please tell.

Comment: Voluntarily? Because he forgot and got on the train anyway? Which version of English?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Sorry to say, but I'm new to English.stackexchange.com, so don't fully understand what are you asking?

Comment: Did he go into work because he wanted to (he volunteered to give up his holiday)? Or because he was called in (he was told to give up his holiday)? Or because he forgot that he was supposed to be on holiday? And the term may be different in Indian English from British English or American English. (I'm not sure there is a term in British English, actually. *Idiot*, maybe!)

Comment: @AndrewLeach He was called to work on a holiday.

Comment: Thanks. Clarifications should go into the question, because comments are ephemeral (and may not be read). I've done that; feel free to improve my edit if you want.

Comment: Poor Sod comes to mind

Comment: By 'holiday', do you mean (1) a public holiday, i.e. a day on which people do not normally work; or (2) a vacation day (as I believe they are referred to in the USA)?

Comment: @TrevorD Number (1), a public holiday

Comment: Thanks. As Andrew Leach has already said "Clarifications should go into the question". As he did, I have edited the question for you.

Comment: I don't know of any specific terms for the person or the cancelled leave, but I wonder whether your colleague might have said "bump", not *pump*. I could understand someone referring to leave being *bumped*, i.e. moved to a new position (date).

Comment: @TrevorD Yes, there is a great possibility of that.

Comment: Have amplified my comment and posted it as an answer.

Comment: I wonder if your friend heard or was talking about *comp time* (short for 'compensatory time'). Sometimes when an employee has to work a weekend or a time they normally wouldn't have to, the employer then gives them a different day off or some comp time.

Comment: I would just say: called in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any specific terms for the person or the cancelled leave, but I wonder whether your colleague might have said "bump", not "pump".

I could understand someone referring to the leave being *bumped*, *i.e.* moved to a new position (date). (See definitions in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bump)).

The alternative day off may also be referred to (at least in the UK) as a "day off *in lieu*", *i.e.* as a day off *instead of* the public holiday. (See definition in [Oxford Dictionary Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lieu?q=in%20lieu).)  In fact, in the UK you will sometimes be entitled to *two* alternative days off if you were required to work on a public holiday.

Answer (score 0):

A "Stakhanovite" ? From Aleksei Grigorevich Stakhanov, a Soviet miner with phenomenal productivity in 1935. It is now known that it was fictitious, to encourage the others.

"Workaholic" could do, but doesn't specify that one is working even during his/her holidays.

The corresponding substantives are "stakhanovism" and "workaholism" (neologisms).

Comment: This answer was apparently written *before* the question was clarified to indicate that the person was *required* to work on a holiday.

Answer (score 0):

At my company (in Los Angeles), we would say we got called in for some 'golden time', which meant 200% pay. 99% of the time this is understood to be because of a holiday.

Comment: This is commentary on another post, not an answer
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

"What is that leave is called?" It's called a Comp Day.  It is compensation for working a holiday, weekend or anytime you normally wouldn't.  Some companies will compensate with 1 1/2 to 2 times the amount of time.

Comment: I think this is answering the exact opposite of what the question asked, since a comp day is a day you get off for previously having worked overtime, not a day of leave that you're working overtime on, when you should have not been working at all.